Как сделать так, чтобы в джанго при нажатии кнопки был переход на другую страницу?
Есть кнопка "регистрация".Как сделать так, чтобы при ее нажатии открывалась другая страница сайта?

как сделать? написать код, примеры которого вы найдете, если почитаете документацию.
